# error: node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF by npm start on debian server

Tags: node.js, express, debian, bcrypt

**Hallo,**
If I try to `npm start` I get this error:

```
error: /home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF header /home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF header {"code":"ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED","stack":"Error: /home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF header\n    at load (/home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/loady/lib/loady.js:109:11)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/lib/native/binding.js:11:33)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)\n    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/lib/native/hkdf.js:10:17)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)"}
error: /home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF header Error: /home/kyrill/msh/backend/node_modules/bcrypto/build/Release/bcrypto.node: invalid ELF header
```

I don't know how to solve it ...

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const upload = require('express-fileupload');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const winston = require('winston');

const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/upload');
const gutachtenRoute = require('./routes/gutachten');
const userRoute = require('./routes/user');

const db = require('./lib/db');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');
const role = require('./middleware/role');
const app = express();

require('./lib/logging')();

db.init().then(() => winston.info("Orbit DB connected"));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(upload());

app.use('/api/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/api/upload', auth, uploadRoute);
app.use('/api/gutachten', auth, gutachtenRoute);
app.use('/api/user', [auth, role], userRoute);


app.listen(process.env.API_PORT, () => winston.info('API Start: http://127.0.0.1:' + process.env.API_PORT));
```

**places where bcrypt is used:**

user.js is a model

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

router.get('/getall', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(User.getAll());
})

router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = User.validateRegister(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(422).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne(req.body.email);
    if(user) return res.status(400).send('User with this email already exist');

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    res.send(User.create(req.body));
});

router.post('/update', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = User.validateUpdate(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(422).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne(req.body.email);
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User with this email not exist');

    if(req.body.password) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    } else {
        req.body.password = user.password;
    }

    await User.update(req.body);
    res.send(User.getAll());
})

router.post('/del', async (req, res) => {
    // const { error } = User.validateDelete(req.body);
    // if(error) return res.status(422).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne(req.body.email);
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User with this email not exist');

    await User.delete(req.body);
    res.send(User.getAll());
})

module.exports = router;
```

auth.js is routes:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = User.validateLogin(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(422).send(error.details[0].message);

    const user = await User.findOne(req.body.email);
    if(!user) res.status(404).send('Invalid email or password');

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPassword) res.status(404).send('Invalid email or password');

    const token = User.generateAuthToken(req.body)
    res.json(token);
})

module.exports = router;
```

**local on my macos it work without problems**

I tried to npm audit fix also with --force , but I get this error:

```
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/haadcode/ipfs-pubsub-room.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Also, I tried to install it from new with `npm i bcryptjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are creating the build on MAC-OS and running that on debian OS. This(invalid ELF header) happens when you build on one architecture and then attempt to use the same built addon on a different architecture (or platform in some cases).

What you can do on the debian server, remove the `node modules` and regenerate them that could solve the problem:

Remove the node modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then generate the same modules for linux using the following command:

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have installed `bcrypto` package that is using the native addon, that for some reason cannot be installed on the machine you are using. Do `npm uninstall bcrypto`, it is okay to just uninstall it, as you are using `bcryptjs` version that does not use native features.

Comment: Can you specify the version which doesn't use the native features? I think that would answer the question more accurately.

Comment: Only `bcryptjs` does not use native features. `bcrypt` is a native addon for Node.js.

Comment: I think `bcryptjs` is being used, he might not be using it(bcrypt) but have installed it that could be the case.

Comment: That is what my answer states, actually.